# Reference is adding item to array

Tags: php, arrays, reference

I have the following method where you pass a list of items in, and the first item is what you want to see if it exists, and the following items are the path to the item.

In the following I have 2 `print_r` statements, one before the `for` and one after it.

```
public function exists(){
    $keys  = func_get_args();
    $value = array_shift($keys);

    $ref = &$_SESSION;
    print_r($_SESSION);
    for($x = 0; $x < sizeof($keys); $x++){
        $ref = &$ref[$keys[$x]];
    }
    print_r($_SESSION);
    if(!is_array($ref)){
        unset($ref);
        return false;
    }
    $found = in_array($value, $ref);
    unset($ref);
    return $found;
}
```

and when I call it like this:

```
$obj->exists(123, "cart");
```

I get these two arrays from those `print_r`'s:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [email] => xxx@xxx.com
    [user] => TheColorRed
    [first] => Billy
    [last] => Bob
    [ZingLoggedIn] => 1
)
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [email] => xxx@xxx.com
    [user] => TheColorRed
    [first] => Billy
    [last] => Bob
    [ZingLoggedIn] => 1
    [cart] => 
)
```

My question is, why is it adding `cart` to the array? It should only be checking to see if it exists.

Comment: Try to enable `E_ALL` error reporting level and check your logs first. PS: your `unset` is completely redundant there.

Comment: Interesting.  Wouldn't an undefined offset notice be raised in the for loop?  Maybe do an isset check and break if it returns false.

Comment: @zerkms I have `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT` and `display_errors = On`

Comment: @The Boogie Man: and you don't get notices/warnings for this code?

Comment: nope I get no errors and/or warnings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the side effect of using references on array elements; if the element doesn't exist it gets created. The `unset()` afterwards doesn't change that. Consider not using references; since you're only reading the values, there should be no copy-on-write taking place:

```
public function exists()
{
    $keys  = func_get_args();
    $value = array_shift($keys);

    $ref = $_SESSION;
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        if (!isset($ref[$key])) {
            return false;
        }
        $ref = $ref[$key];
    }
    return is_array($ref) && in_array($value, $ref);
}
```

Comment: will this work for `$obj->exists("cat", "item1", "item2")` -> `$array['item1']['item2']`?

Comment: @The Boogie Man: what if you try before you ask?

Comment: @TheBoogieMan It won't create array elements; with a function called `exists()` I wouldn't expect that kind of side effect anyway.

Comment: @Ja͢ck but why don't you use `isset` as well?

Comment: I added `&& array_key_exists($key, $ref)` to the if statement because it was saying the index "cart" doesn't exist. Is it a good idea to add that?

Comment: @zerkms Yeah, somehow I thought that accessing non-existing elements from an array would not raise a notice ... must be the morning time.

Comment: I was able to use this to create a method that gets a count as well! thanks!